# Shader Syntax vector = vec3(a,b,c) in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, struct

One simple question: I like the simple creation of vectors in OpenGL Shader language:

```
vector = vec3(a,b,c);
```

How would you code the C++-struct or class that would allow this exact code in C++?

Comment: If you're only concerned by the constructor, it's trivial. The real interest in this datatype is the operations you can do with them (addition, products, permutations, normalisation, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by writing a `vec3` constructor that accepts three floats.

```
class vec3
{
public:
    vec3( float x_, float y_, float z_ )
    : x(x_)
    , y(y_)
    , z(z_)
    {}

    vec3( const vec3 &src )
    {
        *this = src;
    }

    vec3& operator =( const vec3 &src )
    {
        x = src.x;
        y = src.y;
        z = src.z;
        return *this;
    }

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

What is more interesting is how to achieve permutation behaviour, like

```
vec3 a( 1, 2, 3 );
vec3 b = a.yzx; // 2, 3, 1
vec3 c = a.yyx; // 2, 2, 1
```

Comment: By the way, you needn't underscore. `:x(x), y(y), z(z)` works too

Comment: Hello @infact, thanks a lot! I realised there is one line missing to have it behave like in GLSL: after Public: `vec3() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}` With this line you can also say e.g. `vec3 my_variable;`

Comment: Yes. There is really no limit to the number of ways you might want to construct a vector. For performance reasons I would not initialize the members to any particular value automatically. Don't forget to add a copy constructor and assignment operator!

Comment: Hi @infact, I'm pretty new to constructors and such stuff, but what you say seems promising. If you could provide a copy and assignment operator? Also one of the greatest things about what should be possible would be an add-operator (vec3 = vec3 + vec3)

Comment: Hey, I got the constructors right: `bool operator== (vec3 v2) {  return(x == v2.x && y == v2.y && z == v2.z); };
    bool operator!= (vec3 v2) {  return (x != v2.x | y != v2.y | z != v2.z);  };
    vec3 operator+ (vec3 v2)  {  return vec3(x+v2.x, y+v2.y,z+v2.z);  };
    vec3 operator- (vec3 v2)  {  return vec3(x-v2.x, y-v2.y,z-v2.z);  }`

Comment: Looks like you've already worked it out, but I added it to the source sample.

Answer (score 3):

All this work has been done, no need to rewrite it all yourself. You could use [GLMmath](http://glm.g-truc.net/)